# Bootstrap V4 Modal Effect Background not stable

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e1vY.png)Modal opening with a form URL bar. When user clicked on a bar, Modal opens with URL bar and the name of the website. Now the problem is when modal opens and user move the cursor in the area of the opening bar the background bar turns to white or disturb.

Bootstrap code i tried

```
<div class="container-fluid">

   <!-- Form trigger modal -->
<form action="testiing bars.php" method="get" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputlg"></label>
    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text" name="website">
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="formModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Submit URL</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to solve this .?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for adding background scroll to popup as usability feature, may be it will help:

```
/*allow modal scroll behind*/
html { overflow-y: scroll !important; }
body .modal-open { overflow: visible; }
```

Comment: No .. same problem.
Actually the thing is I asked the same question in different forums and end up that this was my browser issue. I was using chrome before now the problem is this is only happening in chrome. I still don't know why.

Comment: Chrome is usually the most forgiving browser.. There is probably some conflicting styles or focus grabbing script, try to simplify by removing things..